# Link to mu4e search queries not available

Tags: mu4e

Although I'm perfectly able to store an org mode link to a particular email, linking to a query somehow doesn't work.

The described[0] option `mu4e-org-link-query-in-headers-mode` is missing at all:
[image: screenshot]

mu (mail indexer/searcher) version 1.0

GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.22, cairo version 1.17.3) of 2020-08-28

[0] https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Org_002dmode-links.html

Comment: That variable is not set to work with Emacs's customize. Try `(setq mu4e-org-link-query-in-headers-mode t)`.

Comment: Thank you @jagrg. Added the line to init.el, alas to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe that variable is not available in the version you're using. Can you check using M-x describe-variable?

Comment: Seems available: `mu4e-org-link-query-in-headers-mode’s value is t`

Comment: `mu4e-org-link-query-in-headers-mode` solve this issue for me as well. This can probably be accepted as explicit answer rather than a comment.